# Getting weights of raw materials in the finished good (multiplying weights across relationships) in Cypher/neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here's a drawn concept of my node map & relationships in neo4j:

[image]

I would like to return a list of the raw materials with the component percents of the final finished goods...

My query returns this which isn't right, it only shows the two most immediate semi-finished goods that go into the finished good:

[image]

There are also additional complexities which I haven't figured out such as the transfer_to relationship where a material sku is transfered to a different plant and the % would be 100%. It's in my data model but I'm not sure how to multiply those as well.

Help would be appreciated - I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your sample data here http://console.neo4j.org/, and share it, with the expected input and output. It will be easier to play around and get the solution

Comment: In absence of the sample data it looks to me like your path isn't long enough. Try:

Comment: MATCH p = (sku_input)-[:GOES_INTO *]->(sku_output)
Your query is only finding the the nodes with hop = 1 from (sku_output) not the complete path.

Comment: This did the trick: match p = (sku_input:SKU)-[:GOES_INTO|TRANSFERS_TO*1..10]->(sku_output:SKU)
where  NOT (:SKU)-[:GOES_INTO]->(sku_input)
return sku_input,reduce(res = 1.00, r IN relationships(p) | res*tofloat(r.WGHT))